# EV3 Error and VM Program Instruction Break

Tags: mindstorms, technic, lego-group, ev3-g

I'm making a program which is very complex and large but it does not contain any Arrays in it. Weird thing is, last night it worked fine but today when I downloaded the exactly same thing into the EV3 it shows a triangle with exclamation mark symbol with orange status light.

This happens halfway when it tries to run a switch with a Logic Variable. Occasionally I would get a "VM Program Instruction Break". Any idea how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE: It turns out there was a compiler issue in the EV3 desktop programming software. LEGO has released a fix in v1.2.2 of both the Home and Education versions. Upgrading your software will fix this problem.**

Read more about the problem and the fix [in this pdf from the Seshan Brothers](http://ev3lessons.com/translations/en-us/beyond/BranchingError.pdf).

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

Some suggestions from the [LEGO MINDSTORMS EV3 Facebook group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/legomindstorms/permalink/526294404185457/):

1. Too many named loops in your code
2. Too many blocks in a loop
3. Try to avoid using too many loop interrupts
4. A problem with the copy/paste - delete the pasted portion of the program and make it from scratch